# Why is an error coming in my untouched build.gradle file?

Tags: flutter, firebase, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I was receiving this error in my build.gradle file (under android > app [This is for flutter in Android Studio]). The error is on 'Properties' and 'Gradle Exception'.

How do I fix this error, and is it necessary to fix it?

[image: 1]

I haven't tried to change anything, and it was like this by default when I first opened the file.

Comment: Don't worry these error are not getting any issue with our app.

Comment: This specific code try catch is used for error handling, incase if your flutter has some issues before generating a build.

Comment: Welcome to SO. t’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error.
If you want to remove the warning in GradleExeption, just remove it and replace it with RuntimeException.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).